# Filter and map by grouping data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an array of objects, where I have the following fields: `title`, `name` e `url`

My data:

```
@array = [
  { id: 1, title: '123', name: 123 },
  { id: 2, title: '123', name: 321 },
  { id: 3, title: '1234', name: 123 },
]
```

I need to group my `data` by title and then make the `map` with the names

```
<%= @array.map do |x| %>
  <div class='col-md-12'>
    <h3><%= x.title %></h3>
    <div class="row">
      <%= @array.filter do |y| %>
        <div class="col-4">
          <% if y.title === x.title %>
            <p><%= t.name %></p>
          <% end %>
        </div>
      <% end.join.html_safe %>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end.join.html_safe %>
```

The return is:

```
title = '123'
    name = '123'
    name = '321'
title = '123'
    name = '123'
    name = '321'
title = '123'
    name = '123'
```

That is, my array comes duplicated ... how to proceed?

Remembering that I am inside the rails view

Comment: In future consider waiting longer before selecting an answer. There's  no rush. A quick selection can discourage other answers, reduce the likilihood that any shortcomings of the selected answer will be noticed and, if a better answer is posted later, place you in the position of leaving the inferior answer selected or changing your selection and disappointing the first recipient of the checkmark. My comments have nothing to do with the answer you selected, which I haven't even read yet.

Comment: An alternative to using `group_by` to form the hash from you can display the desired information is the following: `h = @array.each_with_object(Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = [] }) { |g,h| h[g[:title]] << g[:name] } #=> {"123"=>[123, 321], "1234"=>[123]}`. See the doc for the form of [Hash::new](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-c-new) that takes a block to understand the function of `Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = [] }`. (btw, the downvote is not mine.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're getting duplicate entries since you're `map`ping over all the elements and filtering the array for every element inside the block.

You can use [`Enumerable#group_by`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) to group the array elements by `title`. You can then iterate over the groups and display the title and names of each group. Note that I'm using `item[:name]` to access the values from the hash since your question mentions an array of hashes. You should update it to `item.name` (and other places using hash access) if you're working with objects instead.

```rb
@groups = @array.group_by {|i| i[:title] }
```

```
<% @groups.each do |title, items| %>
  <h3><%= title %></h3>
  <% items.each do |item| %>
    <p><%= item[:name] %></p>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```